# How can I add information about read article on my site to facebook RECENT ACTIVITY?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk

How can I add information about read article on my site to facebook RECENT ACTIVITY (like the Guardian)?

I use php and code:

```
$ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST',
                                    array(
                                      'link' => 'example.com',
                                      'message' => 'Test message'
                                 ));
```

This code posting the message in user's timeline but I want to post message in his recent activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably you wan't to use open graph api, not graph api

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/opengraph-approval/